# Tilelayer url gets rendered 6 times

Tags: next.js, leaflet, react-leaflet

I have a map layer with a custom picture. The problem is, that it gets rendered 6 times although the `Tilelayer` component only gets rendered once.

```
        <MapContainer 
          className='absolute h-[750px] w-[750px] left-[45%] top-[80px] bg-no-repeat bg-cover bg-[#688daa]'
          center={[51.505, -0.09]} zoom={5} scrollWheelZoom={true} noWrap={true}>
        <TileLayer
          noWrap={true}
          url="/allmap.jpg"
        />
        </MapContainer>
```

output:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the expected behaviour of a [Tile Layer](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#tilelayer), although it is supposed to be used with an URL *template*, where some parts of the URL are changed dynamically for proper zoom and x/y position, so that it actually loads different images which form a part of the map, like a puzzle. See also the [Leaflet tutorial about zoom levels](https://leafletjs.com/examples/zoom-levels/).

If your image is not sliced accordingly for such purpose, and you rather have a single big image, you should rather use an [Image Overlay](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#imageoverlay) instead. You can see an example in this [Leaflet tutorial](https://leafletjs.com/examples/overlays/).